# How to store .resx file in javascript object?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

In my application I added the multilanguage support following this documentation.

Now I'm facing an issue: I need to translate also some javascript plugins, so I need to use the .resx string inside the js logic.

A snippet with my strings:

> [image]

For access to those strings I can use the IStringLocalizer in the specific controller, let's suppose that the string above are part of UserController, I can access declaring in the View this:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<UserController> Localizer
```

and then:

```
<h2>@Localizer["LastName"]</h2>
```

Suppose now that I need to pass LastName string in something like a JQuery plugin localization. For doing so, I actually found a workaround, which consists to declare a javascript variable in the required View:

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<UserController> Localizer

@section UserScript{
<script>
    var Lang = {
        PasswordEqual: '@Localizer["PasswordEqual"]',
        PasswordMismatch: '@Localizer["PasswordMismatch"]',
   }
</script>
}
```

so I can access inside the javascript code to the Lang object and localize the plugin eg:

```
$('#birthDate').daterangepicker({
    singleDatePicker: true,
    locale: {
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        daysOfWeek: [
           Lang.Sunday,
           Lang.Monday,
```

This works, but it's really huge to mantain for the following reason:

I need to declare in each .cshtml file which require a script localization the Lang object
I need to set each time the object key for the specific string available in the IStringLocalizer
If I change a string key, I also need to update all the files manually.
What I'm looking for:

I'm looking for a solution that automatically fills the Lang object with all the properties available in the .resx file loaded in the current View. I guess the best place for handle this is _Layout.

Someone could help me?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a Class with all the Localized items, serialize it and send it to the front-end.

```
public class LocalizedItems
{
    public string value1 { get; set; }
    public string value2 { get; set; }
}

var localizedItems = new LocalizedItems();
localizedItems.value1 = "My Value 1";
localizedItems.value2 = "My Value 2";

string json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(localizedItems);
```

Then create a variable in javascript to hold those values. Then when the page is loaded either read the json string from a hidden input

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var localizedItems;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        localizedItems = $.parseJSON($('#HiddenLocalizedItems').val());

        alert(localizedItems.value1);
    });
</script>
```

Or write them to the page directly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var localizedItems = <%= json %>;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert(localizedItems.value1);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: In this way I should create a property for each string? Is possible save all the properties of the resx file? Also, how you specified the Controller which handle the resx file? Usually I do: `IStringLocalizer<UserController> localizer`

Comment: You can also create a List<string> and serialze it. But then every translated object would be index based.

Comment: And a resx file is nothing more than an xml file. So you could theoretically create a method for serializing that.

Comment: The problem is that I have different resx file, so I don't understand how can implement your solution when I have a lot of resx file, each resx file is specifically created for handle the string of a View